# I want to know how to hide particular objects in html page when user logs instead of admin

Tags: html, object, hide, admin

Example

```
<body>
    <a href="settings.htm">Admin Settings</a>
</body>
```

how do I hide this link from the user?

Comment: try `<a  href="settings.htm" style="display:none">Admin Settings</a>`

Comment: Do you want to remove the link using Javascript, or by sending different HTML or CSS from your server?  If you want to do it from your server, tell us what language and libraries or frameworks you're using on the server.

Comment: It would really help to know if you are using Wordpress, or CMS of any sort too

Comment: All the answers that say to use `display:none` are wrong and missing the point.  If you don't want users to have access, ***don't send the link in the first place***.  If you send it, any user who looks at the page source will see the link and be able to enter it in the address bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you differentiate normal user and admin in your site. If you are using php as your server side script. Save usertype in db or session after login.

```
<body>
<?php if($usertype =="admin"){ ?>
<a href="settings.htm">Admin Settings</a>
<?php } ?>
</body>
```

Regards

iijb

Comment: there is no mention of php!!

Comment: how to handle user and admin without any server side script

Comment: sorry for the insufficient details in the question ...iijb ..thats what i was looking for thanks..thank you guys for your support!

Answer (score -1):

Use a flag which sets true if its an admin and depending on the flag set the visibility if this link to false or true